# Using apply or call for member functions that are event handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js

Would it be better practice for event handlers that is an object member for have `this` to refer to the object that is calling the event handler or it to refer to the object that the event handler is a member of?

For the first case, this would be an example of what it would look like:

```
var objects = [
    /* ... */
    {
        a: 5,
        b: 8,
        /* other member variables */
        onSomeEvent: function(data) {
            /* Do stuff with data and this.
               The a and b member variables are referenced with this.effect with the library accessed through this */
        }
    },
    /* ... */
];
function someLibrary() {
    this.doSomeEvent = function(handler, data) {
        this.effect = handler;
        handler.onSomeEvent.call(this, data);
    }
}
var someLibraryInstance = new someLibrary();
someLibraryInstance.doSomeEvent(objects[1], {c:83,d:123});
```

While for the second case, `objects[1].onSomeEvent` would look like this:

```
onSomeEvent: function(library, data) {
    /* Do stuff with library, data and this.
       The a and b member variables are accessed with this.a and this.b. The library is accessed through library */
}
```

while `someLibrary.doSomeEvent` would look like this:

```
this.doSomeEvent = function(handler, data) {
    handler.onSomeEvent(this, data);
}
```

Comment: This question seems too abstract for an answer.  The answer to what `this` should be set to depends upon what the caller needs access to which is not an abstract question, but a practical one based on the actual scenario and what data the caller benefits from having access to.

Comment: I agree with jfriend00, and besides this looks like a bit of a weird design either way. Do you really need to be able to use several `library` variations?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 The library always has the same functions, but might have many instances.

Comment: @jfriend00 What do you mean by what the caller benefits from having access to? The caller simply calls an event handler, which might or might not modify some member variables of the various object parameters that might be passed in, and maybe the caller's member variables as well.

Comment: I'm talking about the coder who writes the event handler (not the coder who triggers the event).  The person who writes the event handler is the one who benefits from what is passed to the event handler and how it's passed.

Comment: These events are in fact for a game. The events are part for items, for example, and the event would be called when the item is "activated". In that event, it would use anything it needs from the game library to do what the item is supposed to do.

Comment: I believe I see what you are trying to do, but the way it is designed is excessively complicated. Instead of using a library as a common set of functions (an API if you will), you are using the library as a class. What you should do is make a 'gameItem' function prototype that handles actions done to the objects as well as their data (a,b,c,d) that simply call the game library's functions when necessary.